# Laravel updating eloquent event: old data same as new

Tags: laravel, observers

I've created `News` model `NewsObserver` associated to it. I want to do some logic with old and new data passed to model on `updated`/`updating` event, but dump of passed model have identical attributes as original attributes, except `'updated_at'`  field. What am I doing wrong?

```
public function updating(News $item)
{
    dd($item);
}
```

Here is where observer is attached

```
use App\Observers\NewsObserver;
use App\Observers\FileObserver;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    News::observe(NewsObserver::class);
    File::observe(FileObserver::class);
}
```

And here is a part of my `NewsObserver` with my `updating` event. `dd` of `$item` contains only old data

```
namespace App\Observers;
use App\News;

class NewsObserver
{
/**
 * Listen to the News updated event.
 *
 * @param  \App\News $item
 * @return void
 */
public function updating(News $item)
{
    $publish_at = request()->input('publish_at');
    $item->publish_at = $publish_at ? $publish_at : $item->publish_at;
    dd($item);
}
```

The example of described `dd` is provided below. New and original attributes are identical except `updated_at` property. But the new title should be `news NEW title`. Of course new data is saved properly in database, but in `updating` or `update` event I don't see 'dirty' attributes

```
#attributes: array:13 [▼
    "id" => 7
    "created_at" => "2016-10-15 19:46:04"
    "updated_at" => "2016-10-15 19:47:11"
    "publish_at" => "2016-10-15 19:46:00"
    "title" => "news OLD title"
    "slug" => "news-old-title"
    "content" => "<p>news OLD content</p>"
    "lead" => ""

#original: array:13 [▼
    "id" => 7
    "created_at" => "2016-10-15 19:46:04"
    "updated_at" => "2016-10-15 19:46:21"
    "publish_at" => "2016-10-15 19:46:00"
    "title" => "news OLD title"
    "slug" => "news-old-title"
    "content" => "<p>news OLD content</p>"
```

Comment: You need to provide more info.  Where are you saving/updating your News model?  Did any new values actually get set?

Comment: I've updated my queston

Comment: Please remove `Solved` from your title and post the solution you found as a proper answer. You can then even accept it.

Answer (score 10):

I think You're looking for:

getOriginal, getAttributes, isDirty, getDirty and so on...

please read docs and use whichever You want:
https://www.laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getOriginal

So I'll do that process this way:

```
$before = $item->toArray();  
$item->title = request()->input('title', $item->title);
// some changes

if($item->save()) { 
  $after = $item->toArray();
  $changes = array_diff_assoc($before, $after);
  Logs::create(compact('before', 'after', 'changes'));
}
```

or that way more elegant:

```
public function updating(News $item) {
    $changes = array();
    foreach($item->getDirty() as $key => $value){
        $original = $model->getOriginal($key);
        $changes[$key] = [
            'old' => $original,
            'new' => $value,
        ];
    }
    Log::create(['model' => __CLASS__, 'changes' => serialize($changes)]);
});
```

or to overload `save` operator in model class with this:

```
trait LogSave {
    public function save(array $options = array()) {
        $changed = $this->isDirty() ? $this->getDirty() : false;
        parent::save();
        if($changed) {
          // log changes
        }
    }
}

class News extends Model {
  use LogSave;
}
```

also I've to ideas:

1. what about having `old = true` flag in model and when doing update actually to create new record and update all `old` version with `old = true` in this case it will be easy to manage/rollback changes just by updating `old = false` necessary version. to keep track of the news id You'll have to keep some `uuid` field in Your table/model.
2. to have `news_revisions` and just to create old `News` (`$item`) object to `NewsRevision` and update the current one.

Comment: I know those methods, but getDirty shows only `updated_at` field, isDirty on title returns false, getAttributes and getOriginal returns data like shown above...

Comment: yep, I want to log some data. As you said I can do this in my controller after calling `save` method but i want to do this in more elegant way, put that code in observer and forget it - let logging be done automatically outside my controllers

Comment: the problem is that your second proposition won't work in my case cause of `getDirty` method, which is returning only `updated_at` field.... Only your first snippet should work, but it is not exactly what I wanted to achieve

Comment: @piotr check last 2 ideas  (:

Comment: @piotr I've updated my answer, can You check the 3rd solution?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

Problem solved. The one thing I didn't post here is the `$item->touch()` method used few lines before. I forgot that may fire update event only on `updated_at` field. My mistake. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Also worth noting that if you have multiple listeners you could have a previous listener changing the original.

So if you have the following in your `EventServiceProvider`:

```
OrderUpdatedEvent::class => [
   RecreateReceiptsListener::class,
   OtherListener::class, // the troublesome one
],
```

Just switch them:

```
OrderUpdatedEvent::class => [
    OtherListener::class, // the troublesome one
    RecreateReceiptsListener::class,   
],
```

Now `getOriginal()` contains the original values.